# Convert list of matrices into table of frequences

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have a list of matrices. Each matrix is the result of a survey. The results look like this (for each question, only one answer can be chosen):

```
[[1]]
   Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4
A1  1  1  1  1
A2  0  0  0  0
A3  0  0  0  0

[[2]]
   Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4
A1  0  1  1  0
A2  1  0  0  1
A3  0  0  0  0

[[3]]
   Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4
A1  1  0  0  1
A2  0  0  0  0
A3  0  1  1  0
```

Now I would like to take these results, and get them into a format that looks something like this (HairEyeColor is a multidimensional array to start [built-in r dataset]):

```
> as.data.frame.table(HairEyeColor)
    Hair   Eye    Sex Freq
1  Black Brown   Male   32
2  Brown Brown   Male   53
3    Red Brown   Male   10
4  Blond Brown   Male    3
5  Black  Blue   Male   11
6  Brown  Blue   Male   50
7    Red  Blue   Male   10
8  Blond  Blue   Male   30
9  Black Hazel   Male   10
......
```

For the sticklers (but note that number of questions and number of answers will vary per survey):

```
    Q1    Q2      Q3    Q4   Freq
1  Q1A1  Q2A1    Q3A1  Q4Al    1
2  Q1A2  Q2A1    Q3A1  Q4Al    1
3  Q1A2  Q2A2    Q3A1  Q4Al    2
4  Q1A2  Q2A2    Q3A1  Q4Al    1
5  Q1A2  Q2A1    Q3A2  Q4Al    4
6  Q1A2  Q2A1    Q3A1  Q4A2    4
7  Q1A2  Q2A2    Q3A2  Q4A1    2
8  Q1A2  Q2A2    Q3A1  Q4A2    4
9  Q1A2  Q2A2    Q3A2  Q4A2    1
...
```

If I had to make my own function, I suppose I could brute force it and use each possible combination as a key to a key/value pair.

But I have no idea where to begin otherwise. I am guessing there is already a function to handle this that just I can't seem to find, any ideas?

Comment: Maybe... but your example data and example output do not match up, so there is no way of knowing.

Comment: I'm dealing with something like this in an AI script, matching range propensities to real-time results. To be honest, the best solution I think, is to create an oop model to file everything as it happens. Or, if the data already exists, to parse through it line by line. What language are you using?

Comment: @42- There is no set shape the survey data can take. It could have 3 columns and 5 rows, or it could have 10 columns and 2 rows. HairEyeColor was just an example I had on hand.

Comment: If everything is unknown or going to be generated, it is best to build methods into functions, perhaps representing each question as a single argument derived from 'question' class. Have the objects act on the results, and file the results as they happen. This might sound like work, but it will be worth it in the end.

Comment: @bigcodeszzer R language.

Comment: No clue at that. I would use something like Java.

Comment: Pair it with something like sql if you need stats?

Comment: @bigcodeszzer Have to use R, sorry. The output must be in a form that allows statistical manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so this is the function I ended up creating. Had to learn a lot of new tricks.

```
createCombinationArray = function(data) 
{
  dataLength = length(data)

  if(dataLength <= 0)
    return(NULL)

  d = dim(data[[1]])

  numQuestions = d[1]
  numAnswers = d[2]      

  #the length of size is the number of dimensions in multi
  #the values of size represent the number of rows
  size = rep.int(numAnswers, numQuestions)

  #create a zero'ed out multid-array
  multi = array(0, size)

   #Loop through each survey matrix
   for(i in 1:dataLength)
   {
      indices = rep(1, numQuestions)
      #loop through each question in the survey
       for(j in 1:numQuestions)
       {
         #loop through each answer and determine selected value
         #(in my case its where a 1 exists or not 0)
         for(k in 1:numAnswers)
         {
           if((data[[i]][j, k]) != 0)
             #build up the indices that will be used to update the multid-array
             indices[j] = k
         }
       }
      #use a matrix to access the appropriate dimensions
      #this way the dimensions can be defined dynamically (e.g. not hard coded like "multi[x,y,z,w]")
      multi[matrix(indices, 1)] = multi[matrix(indices, 1)] + 1
   }

  return(multi)
}
```

To get the desired format:

```
createCombinationTable = function(data)
{
  return(as.data.frame.table(createCombinationArray(data)))
}
```